# React Native iOS simulator network images not loading

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I have a react native app created. Image assets and react-native-vector-icons are loading correctly. But network images are not loading. Images are being fetched from aws as signed url. Those links are working correctly on android.

Tried this fix - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428

I don't think the patch fix is required https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-657284028 as my `react-native` version is `0.70.1`

App Information

```
"react-native": "0.70.1"
Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
```

Comment: Please add new image url so i can check it.

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq example url http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reacted/profile_image/kane-brown.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAY4GBF6Z3MMICD4H7%2F20230208%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230208T050054Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=de4bd14c4d96e581a4fe23950293854f14a0f90f3ec9a158e167c5212ee8d8a8

Answer (score 2):

ok. the URL you shared is http and iOS does not all http request. to allow http request in iOS please add this to **info.plist** file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

for more details please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) question  and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/9570734)